# Abnormal behaviour in OCI_BIND_BY_NAME

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I was using the following code to bind variables using `oci_bind_by_name` but getting returned only single row even though multiple rows were available.

```
<?php 
    $queryArr = array(11423,24242,2463,23434);
    $sqlarr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($queryArr); $i++) {
        array_push($sqlarr, ":B$i");
    }
    $sqlstr = implode(",", $sqlarr);
    $sql = "SELECT COL1, COL2, STATUS FROM TAB1 WHERE P_KEY = :USR_ID AND S_COL IN (" . $sqlstr . ") ORDER BY STATUS";
    $this->sth = oci_parse($this->con, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($this->sth, ":USR_ID", $usrid);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($queryArr); $i++) {
        $bid = $queryArr[$i];
        oci_bind_by_name($this->sth, ":B$i", $bid);
    }
    oci_execute($this->sth);
?>
```

After spending 3 hours finding the error in the code I found that the problem is with `OCI_BIND_BY_NAME`. I changed the above code as below and I was getting all the rows now.

```
<?php 
    $queryArr = array(11423,24242,2463,23434);
    $sqlarr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($queryArr); $i++) {
        array_push($sqlarr, ":B$i");
    }
    $sqlstr = implode(",", $sqlarr);
    $sql = "SELECT COL1, COL2, STATUS FROM TAB1 WHERE P_KEY = :USR_ID AND S_COL IN (" . $sqlstr . ") ORDER BY STATUS";
    $this->sth = oci_parse($this->con, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($this->sth, ":USR_ID", $usrid);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($queryArr); $i++) {
    //Changed code --START--
        $bindName = ":B".$i;
        oci_bind_by_name($this->sth, $bindName, $queryArr[$i]);
    //Changed code --END--
    }
    oci_execute($this->sth);
?>
```

Can someone please explain the reason behind this...?

So as a summary:

> When creating a variable by appending string and using it in `OCI_BIND_BY_NAME` then it's working fine but when I am directly appending string in the function then it's not working correctly. Also, it's not giving any error message. It's getting executed but returning only single row.

Comment: Isn't that how [oci_bind_by_name()](http://php.net/oci_bind_by_name) is meant to work? «Binds a PHP **variable** to an Oracle placeholder». Perhaps it's returning `false`; you don't check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example is binding `$bid` in each iteration, i.e the same variable location (memory address) is reused.  See the related example 'Example #3 Binding with a foreach() loop' in the [oci_bind_by_name() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php):

```
foreach ($ba as $key => $val) {

    // oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $val) does not work
    // because it binds each placeholder to the same location: $val
    // instead use the actual location of the data: $ba[$key]
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, $key, $ba[$key]);
}
```

Comment: OK, but I am updating the value at the location `$bid`, Will the updated value not be used at the time of binding if not then why? 

Variables are meant to have a value at the same location which can be changed.

Comment: It seems, It is binding the placeholder with the variable `$val` and when loop completes the `$val` has only the last iteration value, so all placeholders points to that same value. To resolve this we can create new variables inside loop or use Array Index as shown in the example.